# Setting visibility of a link in code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net

i have this in source code:

```
<a href="CreateAlbum.aspx" id="createalbumlink">                    
                Create New Album
            </a>
```

now i want to set its visibility in code behind. How can i do so? I have this link within ListView Control. 
I replaced the above with

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" PostBackUrl="~/CreateAlbum.aspx"> Create New Album1</asp:LinkButton>
```

still couldnt detect in codebehind.

SOurce code:

```
   <form id="form1" runat="server">

    <asp:ListView ID="lvAlbums" runat="server"
            DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" GroupItemCount="3" 
            InsertItemPosition="LastItem">            
            <LayoutTemplate>                
                    <table border="1">
                       <tr ID="groupPlaceholder" runat="server">
                       </tr>
                    </table>                       
            </LayoutTemplate>                                              
            <GroupTemplate>
                    <tr>
                        <td ID="itemPlaceholder" runat="server">
                        </td>
                    </tr>
             </GroupTemplate>             
             <ItemTemplate>
                    <td id="Td3" width="150px" height="150px" align="center" style="background-color: #e8e8e8;color: #333333;">
                    <asp:HiddenField ID="hfPhotoID" runat="server" Value='<%# Eval("DefaultPhotID") %>' />
                    <a href='<%# "Photos.aspx?AlbumID="+Eval("AlbumID") %>'> 
                    <asp:Image CssClass="Timg" runat="server" ID="imPhoto" ImageUrl='<%# "ThumbNail.ashx?ImURL="+Eval("Photo") %>' />
                    </a>
                    <br />                    
                    <b><asp:Label ID="lblAlbumName" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("AlbumName") %>'></asp:Label>   </b>
                    </td>                
                </ItemTemplate>

                <InsertItemTemplate>
                <td id="Td3" width="150px" height="150px" runat="server" align="center" style="background-color: #e8e8e8;color: #333333;">
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" PostBackUrl="~/CreateAlbum.aspx"> Create New Album1</asp:LinkButton>
             <%--   <a href="CreateAlbum.aspx" id="createalbumlink" runat="server">                    
                    Create New Album
                </a>--%>
                </td>              
                </InsertItemTemplate>             
            </asp:ListView>

        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
            ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:SLIITComDBConnectionString %>" 

        SelectCommand="SELECT Album.AlbumID, Album.DefaultPhotID, Album.AlbumName, PhotAlbum.Photo FROM Album INNER JOIN PhotAlbum ON Album.DefaultPhotID = PhotAlbum.PhotoID where album.userid=@userid">
       <SelectParameters>
       <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="userid" Type="int32"  QueryStringField="id" />

         <%--<asp:SessionParameter Name="userid" Type="String"  SessionField="UserId" />--%>
</SelectParameters>
        </asp:SqlDataSource>
    </form>
```

Comment: LinkButton1 It is strange that you don't see LinkButton1 control, check open and close tags. Try to regenerate your *.designer.cs file

Comment: could it have something to do with the fact that linkbutton in within ListView?

Comment: Paste your aspx code with ListView

Answer (score 1):

Well you can't access the `LinkButton` directly since its inside a `ListView`, you can iterate through each item in the ListView and find the link button using [`FindControl`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/486wc64h.aspx) and then set the Visible property. Something like:

```
foreach (ListViewItem item in listView.Items)
{
    LinkButton linkButton = item.FindControl("LinkButton1") as LinkButton;
    if (linkButton != null)
        linkButton.Visible = false;
}
```

the above will disable `LinkButton` for all the items.

Comment: okay , i pasted your code and there are no red lines so i guess it should work. I am tackling with another error, as soon as i solve that one and your code works i will mark your answer. But wouldnt this code set the visibility of all the linkbuttons? suppose if i have multiple linkbuttons and i want to set the visibility of just one particular linkbutton?

Comment: @Arbaaz, I have mentioned that in my answer that it will set the visibility of all the linkbuttons to false, you can filter out the particular link button in your the foreach loop using an `if` statement

Comment: okay i tried your code, and although there were no errors it still did not work.

 if (Session["UserId"].ToString() == Request.QueryString["Id"].ToString())
        {
            foreach (ListViewItem item in lvAlbums.Items)
            {
                LinkButton linkButton = item.FindControl("LinkButton1") as LinkButton;
                if (linkButton != null)
                    linkButton.Visible = false;
            }
        }
THe value of session and query string is matching (i used break point) but still i am able to see the link on running the page

Answer (score 0):

Use the OnClick event handler of the LinkButton and toggle the visibility there.

Comment: I Cant find the event handler icon in properties. The link is within ListViw i can only select it from the source.
and i want to set the visibility on page load.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit**

Try using FindControl:

```
LinkButton LinkButton1 = (LinkButton)ListView1.FindControl("LinkButton1");
LinkButton1.Visible = false;
```

Comment: it says 
cannot implicitly convert type 'system.web.ui.control' to 'system.web.ui.webcontrols.linkbutton'

Comment: there are no errors now except for NullRefrence . I applied breakpoint and it seems that control is not reaching the linkbutton1 which is in <ItemTemplate> the control just scans Item template.

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere in the code behind do this:

```
LinkButton1.Visible = false;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
LinkButton1.Visible = false; //control will not rendered
LinkButton1.Attribute["styles"] = "display:none"; // control will be hidden
```

You can alse use  tag, but you have to add runat="server" param

Comment: I am not able to detect LinkButton1 in codebehind, probably because its inside ListViw.